# NHibernate: Require inner join instead of left join for References

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

How can I change the default join type to be an inner join instead of a left outer join for mappings when I use References?

For Example:

```
public class SomeClassMap : ClassMap<SomeClass>
{
   public SomeClassMap()
   {
     Id(x => Id);
     References(x => x.Account);
   }
}
```

this usually turns out to be something like this...

```
FROM SomeClass  SC
LEFT OUTER JOIN Account A 
ON SC.Id = A.Id
```

I'd like to have this be an inner join instead of a left outer join. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Similar question here:

[Inner or Right Outer Join in Nhibernate and Fluent Nhibernate on Many to Many collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057310/inner-or-right-outer-join-in-nhibernate-and-fluent-nhibernate-on-many-to-many-col)

I'm assuming this also applies to one to many relationships.  Someone please chime in if this does not hold true anymore.