# Nhibernate force inner join on Many-to-one relation

Tags: nhibernate

I have a many-to-one relation mapped between two entities A and B. I will use Fruit and Color to simulate my scenario:

Assuming all the fruit has only one color. So I have a Color property in my Fruit class and in my mapping code for Fruit I have:

```
ManyToOne(f=>f.Color, mapper=>mapper.Column("ColorId"));
```

And the generated SQL has the following:

```
Select f0_.Name, f0...From Fruit f0_
  left outer join Color c0_
  on f0_.ColorId = c0_.id
```

I am wondering if there is any way for force an inner join instead of outer join. Because from the business perspective, a fruit without a color is not really a fruit and shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *Criteria API*, we can achieve both `left` and/or `inner` join:

LEFT

```
// default left outer join
var leftResult = session.CreateCriteria<Fruit>()
  .SetFetchMode("Color", NHibernate.FetchMode.Join)
  .List<Fruit>();
```

INNER

```
// explicit inner join
var innerResult = session.CreateCriteria<Fruit>()
  .CreateCriteria("Color", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
  .List<Fruit>();
```

*leftResult* will contain all `Fruits` while *innerResult* will contain only these having `Color`

#### *EDIT: specific solution applied inside mapping*

*Well, the default left join cannot be changed: [Inner or Right Outer Join in Nhibernate and Fluent Nhibernate on Many to Many collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057310). But what about using other NHibernate feature:*

Let's say that our `Fruit`, is only meaningful, if there is a `Color`. If this is true, and we won't ever need these table records without *Color* selected (having column `ColorId` set to NULL) there is a way how to adjust mapping:

```
// Mapping Fruit
Table("Fruits");
Where("colorId IS NOT NULL");
...
```

or in XML

```
  <class name="Fruit" table="Fruits" where="colorId IS NOT NULL" ... >
```

(see http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class)

So this, won't change LEFT to INNER, but at least the mapping will allow to have only colorful fruits...

Comment: While this can be a valuable solution, I am looking for similar things in mapping, but not at query level. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I see. But I am afraid that this is only solution. Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057310. BUT! There is an option ... i extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think that answers my question.